# Wordpress foreach loop displaying too many categories -- just want current post's category

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I want to create a loop that grabs the three most recent posts and displays each post's title and categories. The loop I have is currently grabbing the correct values for each post but the foreach loop is appending all the previous post's values to as well so by the third post it shows that it has all the previous post's categories in addition to the categories unique to the third post.

For further clarity -- if Post1 is categorized as A and B and Post2 is categorized as C and D, Post2 is showing that it is categorized as ABCD. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<section class="blog-index">
        <?php 
            $args = array('showposts' => 3);
            $recent = new WP_Query( $args );

            if( $recent->have_posts() ): 
                echo '<div class="blog-index-list">';

                while ( $recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); 
                $categories = get_the_category();
                        foreach($categories as $category) {
                            $cat .= $category->name;                            
                        };


                    echo '<article>                     
                        <h2><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' .get_the_title(). '</a></h2>
                        <p class="post-cats"> ' . $cat . '</p>
                        <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'' .
                        '<div class="blog-index-button et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_module et_pb_button_alignment_center">
                            <a class="et_pb_button  et_pb_button_3 et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">READ POST</a>
                        </div>                  
                        </article>';
                endwhile; 
                echo '</div>';
            endif; 
            wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>      
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you're not clearing your $cat variable in between grabbing posts. When you use .= to append data to $cat, you need to set $cat = "" between each call of the foreach.